# Can I add own Validator to ValidatorPluginManager?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have got own validator, which uses Entity Manager for work.

Is it possible to add this validator to ValidatorPluginManager (and set Entity Manager to it) and then call it like:

```
$factory = new InputFactory();
    $factory->createInput(
        array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => array(),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'MyValidator', 
                    'options' => array(//options for validator))
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend\InputFilter\Factory allows you to set the default validator chain. When you do, that validator chain is cloned for each input. This allows you to set defaults, such as the plugin manager instance to use.

```
$pluginManager = new ValidatorPluginManager();
// do some work with it
$validatorChain = new ValidatorChain();
$validatorChain->setPluginManager($pluginManager);
$factory = new InputFilterFactory();
$factory->setDefaultValidatorChain($validatorChain);
```